# How to find Vce SAT in NPN transistor datasheet

Tags: transistors

I am trying to find out the VCE value when the collector current is 150 mA (Controlled by the load). the base current is 4 mA. What is the VCESAT value when the base current is 4 mA?
part: BC817-40

[Datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC817_BC817W_BC337.pdf)

Comment: Figures 4, 5 and 6 in the datasheet have the information you're looking for.

Comment: @Nick I am looking for VCESAT

Comment: Sorry, I mean figures 7, 8 and 9.

Comment: If you are looking for a guaranteed worst-case value it's going to be **much** higher than the typical value- maybe ~1V @-55 degrees C with a low hFE specimen.

Comment: @Spehro I operate from 0 to 50 deg C. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Just want to make sure you understand that the curves are not guaranteed behavior - and you can expect a lot of unit-to-unit and temperature variation with your relatively low base current. For example, if you buy the cheapest beta bin you'll likely get worse behaviour than the typical curves even for small quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Figures 10, 11 and 12 you can see a set of graphs for Vce vs collector current at various base currents. Choosing the 4.8mA base current curve as being closest to what you want, you can read the Vce value at around 150mV - 200mV for all three of the transistors at 150mA of current. This is quite typical for a BJT device in saturation.

Note that in practice there is quite a lot of variability in this value between parts/batches and it will change a bit with temperature (as you can see in the other figures 7, 8 and 9).

Comment: Thank you. what might be the hFE at 4 mA of IB?

Comment: hFE is the current gain of the transistor (Ic/Ib), so by definition it will be 150mA/4mA = 38 under those conditions.

Comment: Yes indeed, when the transistor is near or in saturation, less Ic will flow because Vce is low. When Vce > Vcesat (linear mode) the beta (current gain) is much larger ! Then usually beta is plotted as a function of Ic (not Ib !)